# Changed server, now my form doesn't work anymore

Tags: php, forms

```
    <form method=post action=index1.php>
    <input type=hidden name=active value=1>
    <table width="376" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><img src="../../images/spacer.gif" width="1" height="25" /></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top"><?php
        $a=0;
        while(list($key, $val) = each($_POST)) {
        #print "<br>$val -".strlen($val);
        if (strlen($val)>1) {
        $a++;
        }
        }
        if ($a <5) {
        if (!$active==0) {
        print "<b><font color=#ff6600>You probably forgot something.</font></b><br>";
        }
    ?></td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">Name<br />
        <input name=name type=text id="name" value=<?print "\"$name\""?> size=26 maxlength=50></td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">E-mail<br />
        <input name=email type=text id="email" value=<?print "\"$email\""?> size=26 maxlength=50></td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">Subject<br />
          <select name="subject">
            <option value="[Support] Something else" selected="selected">Please select a subject 
            <option value="[Support] Custom type(face)">Custom type(face)
            <option value="[Support] Technical support">Technical support
            <option value="[Support] Licensing">Licensing
            <option value="[Support] Ordering help">Ordering help
            <option value="[Support] Website comments">Website comments
            <option value="[Support] Something else">Something else
        </select></td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">Message<br />
          <textarea name="message" cols="45" rows="12" class="textfield" id="message"></textarea></td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">&nbsp;</td>
        <td align="left" valign="top" bgcolor="#999999">All fields are required. 
          <br />
          <input name="submit" type="submit" value="Submit" />
          <?php
            } else {
            print "<br><b><font color=#ff6600>Thank you! We will come back to you soon.</font></b>";
            $body = "Contact form\n\nName: $name\nSubject: $subject\nEmail: $email\nMessage: $message\n";
            mail("mail@webzovoort.nl",$subject,$body,"From: $email\r\n");
            if ($mailing==1) {
            mail("mail@webzovoort.nl",$subject,"","From: $email\r\n");
            }
            }
        ?>
        <br />
        <br /></td>
        <td width="8" align="left" valign="top">&nbsp;</td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <img src="../../images/various/divider.gif" width="360" height="8" />
  </form>
```

This form was running ok on an other server. But now I moved it doesn't. The form does send an email but it's not filled. It's running on a server with PHP 5.2.12

Comment: `$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated. Try `$_POST` instead.

Comment: `4.1.0 Introduced $_POST that deprecated $HTTP_POST_VARS.` , which country are you reside?

Answer (score 1):

The first thing is

`$HTTP_POST_VARS` is deprecated use `$_POST` instead

Comment: I was about to say the same. +1

Comment: I saw that one but if I change it it still doesn't work. Anything else you can see?

Comment: Ok after change which part is not working i mean is there any error message or warning?

Comment: I changed $HTTP_POST_VARS into $_POST. Got no error message at all.